# Why do certain ferns have roughened spore surface?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, morphology

Ferns such as *Anemia phyllitidis*, [*Blotiella lindeniana*](http://www.plantsystematics.org/users/robbin/5_17_15/upload610/Blotiella_lindeniana_9.jpg.2.jpg), *Ctenitis hirta*, *Cystopterix fragilis*, *Hemionitis palmata* and many others have roughened splity spore surface.

I ask, why is it evolutionary so? Does it have something to do with [Equisetales](http://www.barnes-botany.co.uk/images/equis_flu.jpg) spores, which has long derivates to join up together to spread more effectively? Or more like a convergention with polen of Asteraceae, which is morphologically adapted to zoogamy?